# while loop as long as value doesn't change

Tags: python, while-loop

I need to solve a newbie IQ 70 problem, but can't find a way to do it. I need to quit the while loop if the block_number changes. Can't be that difficult!

```
while await asyncio.sleep(interval, True):

   block_number= get_current_block_number()

   while block_number stays the same:
   
       insert data into table

   else: do something else now     #block_number has changed
```

Comment: You meant quit the external while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you just passed, see if the code below solves your problem:

```
import asyncio

async def main():
    interval = 1
    block_number = get_current_block()

    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(interval, True)

        while True:
            # Here we can check if the number has been modified
            current_block_number = get_current_block()
            if current_block_number != block_number:
                break

            insert_data_into_table()

        do_something_else()

        # And here we update the block number
        block_number = current_block_number

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that opened my eyes that I can't solve the problem only in editing the function where I retrieve the transaction data because it would be ALWAYS the actual block_number. So first I have to get an initial block_number in the main-section, then I can compare the actual block_number in the function with this reference-number!

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of block_number in another variable, then compare those two values in the while loop:

```
block_number = something
original_block_number = block_number

while block_number == original_block_number:
    # do stuff that might change block_number
```

Comment: But then the while block is always "true".
lets say we have block 3:
block_number=3, original_block_number=3 -> while block true
block number changes to 4:
block_number=4, original_block_number=4  -> while block true

Comment: @Soapp I'm assuming that the code inside the `while` loop might possibly change the value of `block_number`.  Otherwise, frankly your question makes no sense.

Comment: @Soapp `original_block_number = block_number` happens _before_ the loop. If you change `block_number` inside the block, this is not going to affect the value of `original_block_number `.

Comment: ok, that was not clear worded:
For every transaction in the bitcoin network:
  Get the block number
  While block number is the same as in the last transaction:
           print stuff
  else: do soemthing else

OK, it dawns to me that this isn't possible the way I intendet to code it. Maybe I need some global variables  *thinking hard*

Comment: @Soapp _While block number is the same as in the last transaction_ That's very different from your question, which said _while block_number stays the same_.